# XSLT - Show only if child contains specific text

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT. Unable to figure out , how to show a particular row only if the child nodes contain one of the specific texts.

In my case we have a list of call logs. The phone number can be of multiple type, but i want show them in table only when the phone number type is either voice or sms.

[Current Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeC3m.png)

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>
<CallLogs>
    <cInfoBj>
        <phNoBJ>
            <phNo>123</phNo>
            <phTypeBj>
                <phTypeName>VOICE</phTypeName>
            </phTypeBj>
        </phNoBJ>
    </cInfoBj>
    <cInfoBj>
        <phNoBJ>
            <phNo>456</phNo>
            <phTypeBj>
                <phTypeName>VOICE</phTypeName>
            </phTypeBj>
            <phTypeBj>
                <phTypeName>SMS</phTypeName>
            </phTypeBj>
        </phNoBJ>
    </cInfoBj>
    <cInfoBj>
        <phNoBJ>
            <phNo>789</phNo>
            <phTypeBj>
                <phTypeName>SMS</phTypeName>
            </phTypeBj>
        </phNoBJ>
    </cInfoBj>
     <cInfoBj>
        <phNoBJ>
            <phNo>890</phNo>
            <phTypeBj>
                <phTypeName>FAX</phTypeName>
            </phTypeBj>
        </phNoBJ>
    </cInfoBj>
</CallLogs>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
      
      <xsl:for-each select="/CallLogs/cInfoBj/phNoBJ">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="phNo"/></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:for-each select="phTypeBj">
                    <div><xsl:value-of select="phTypeName"/></div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
      
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `xsl:for-each` to `xsl:apply-templates`, and define template rules for the different things it can select:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/CallLogs/cInfoBj/phNoBJ"/>
```

then

```
<xsl:template match="phNoBJ[.//phTypeName=('VOICE', 'SMS')]">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="phNo"/></td>
            <td>
                <xsl:for-each select="phTypeBj">
                    <div><xsl:value-of select="phTypeName"/></div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
        </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="phNoBJ"/> <!-drop element if it doesn't match the conditions-->
```

Template rules are the idiomatic way of structuring XSLT code; if you're a beginner, then every time you find yourself writing `xsl:for-each`, consider using `xsl:apply-templates` instead.

Comment: 1. Why is it better to apply templates indiscriminately, then try to catch the nodes you don't want to be processed with empty templates, instead of applying templates conditionally? -- 2. Why is it better to split the process into two (apply templates + match this template) instead of saying simply: apply this template (which is **exactly** what `xsl:for-each` does, according to its definition in the specification).

Comment: Because code evolves. The code written to solve one problem will need to change over time to solve different and bigger problems. You need to start out not with the code that is optimal for the task it is now being asked to perform, but that has the most flexibility to tackle different problems in the future.

Comment: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Your link defines YAGNI as a principle whereby you don't add functionality until it's needed. I agree with that totally. But extensibility is not the same as functionality. If you don't design extensibility in from the start, you're sunk when you need it.

Comment: I have pointed out two reasons why your approach is less than optimal for the current problem. I see no good reason to tolerate this just because maybe some day it will male it easier to write the optimal code for another problem - which will probably never arise. As if all knowledge of XSLT will become extinct and no one will be able to rewrite the code, if necessary.

Comment: Suit yourself. There's no provably optimal answer unless you can predict the future.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/CallLogs/cInfoBj/phNoBJ">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/CallLogs/cInfoBj/phNoBJ[phTypeBj/phTypeName='VOICE' or phTypeBj/phTypeName='SMS']">
```

---

You may need to add a similar predicate to your other `xsl:for-each` instruction if you don't want to list the additional types for numbers with multiple types.